Protect Worksheets using OpenXML from F#
I am attempting to protect worksheets in OpenXML spreadsheet (.xlsx) documents using F# and the OpenXML SDK. I have mostly developed software using and targeting Linux systems; I have only ever really dipped into the .NET ecosystem a little bit in this past year, specifically because at work we are having to deal in bulk with Excel workbooks. I am definitely outside of my wheelhouse.
I have read a great deal of the documentation (e.g., SheetProtection, Worksheet, &c; I even banged my head against the spec trying to get a handle on the structure and relationship of the various elements of the SpreadsheetDocument--although reading this post was the most helpful thing I found for understanding the document structure). I have tried a great deal of variations on solutions I have found online, e.g.:

Making workbook readonly from MVC Controller with OpenXML
OpenXML - Protect all sheets
Excel File Password Protection with Open XML SDK

and I have come up with a couple of solutions that seem like they should work, but Excel always reports the output as being corrupted. (The error message is "We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?"; attempting recovery always results in blank worksheets.)
Here's what I've tried:
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.ExtendedProperties

(* Return a new `SheetProtection` element with desired properties. *)
let ptx () : SheetProtection =
    let mutable p = new SheetProtection()
    p.Password <- "pass"
    p.Sheet <- true
    p


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let fname = argv.[0]
    let newFname = "locked_" + fname
    
    let doc : SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fname, false)
    let newDoc = doc.Clone(newFname, true)
    
    for wsp in newDoc.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts do
        let mutable ws = wsp.Worksheet
        for d in ws.Descendants<SheetProtection>() do
            ws.RemoveChild(d) |> ignore
        ws.InsertAt(ptx(), 0)
    
    newDoc.Save()
    0

I have also tried this version of the ptx() function for generating new SheetProtection elements; I generated the properties by manually protecting a sheet in a test file with a password and extracting them from the resultant <x:sheetProtection /> tag in the worksheet's XML. (I understand that this officially A Hack, but I thought I'd give it a try anyway.)
(* Values taken from locked worksheet in separate test file. *)
let validAlgo = "SHA-512"
let validHash ="Jrtu+148IBi2z6YQUhK/lnIYUo7c9E4xpwBvCcKB4HHYAYETer9MAez6aMe75CPcB80szijGgynrtxMvzPjjig==" 
let validSalt = "IdUWgTwU5c0JMxBS3HORJA=="
let okSpinCount = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value(uint32 100000)

(* Return new SheetProtection element with desired properties. *)
let ptx () : SheetProtection =
    let mutable p = new SheetProtection()
    p.AlgorithmName <- validAlgo
    p.HashValue <- validHash
    p.SaltValue <- validSalt
    p.SpinCount <- okSpinCount
    p.Sheet <- true
    p

Same result.
(I have also noticed that the XML from the files touched by this operation are slightly different--they have scoping prefixes or whatever in front of each of the tag names, but I just don't know enough about XML in general or this schema in particular to know if it matters:
Excerpt of original worksheet file:
<worksheet mc:Ignorable="x14ac">
  <dimension ref="A1:I41"/>
  <sheetViews>
    <sheetView topLeftCell="A34" workbookViewId="0">
      <selection activeCell="K26" sqref="K26"/>
    </sheetView>
  </sheetViews>
  <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="14.3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>
  <cols>
    <col min="1" max="1" width="31.375" customWidth="1"/>
    <col min="2" max="2" width="9.125" customWidth="1"/>
  </cols>

  ...and so forth..


Excerpt of the modified file (at least the <sheetProtection /> tag is in there, that's a good sign, right?):
<x:worksheet mc:Ignorable="x14ac">
  <x:sheetProtection algorithmName="SHA-512" hashValue="Jrtu+148IBi2z6YQUhK/lnIYUo7c9E4xpwBvCcKB4HHYAYETer9MAez6aMe75CPcB80szijGgynrtxMvzPjjig==" saltValue="IdUWgTwU5c0JMxBS3HORJA==" spinCount="100000" sheet="1"/>
  <x:dimension ref="A1:I41"/>
  <x:sheetViews>
    <x:sheetView topLeftCell="A34" workbookViewId="0">
      <x:selection activeCell="K26" sqref="K26"/>
    </x:sheetView>
  </x:sheetViews>
  <x:sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="14.3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>
  <x:cols>
    <x:col min="1" max="1" width="31.375" customWidth="1"/>
    <x:col min="2" max="2" width="9.125" customWidth="1"/>
  </x:cols>

  ...and so forth...


.)
I also tried using SpreadsheetLight, but the constructor for opening a spreadsheet file always threw an InvalidProgramException, so I didn't spend too much time on it.
I would very much appreciate any guidance I could get about this problem in particular, or working with OpenXML more broadly (or heck, even with .NET in general) that I could get.

I've used FlexCel for this (commercial library) and didn't have any problems.

@JimFoye Good to know; thanks for the suggestion. However, a) I work in the public sector, and was hoping to not have to get approval to spend money, and b) It really seems like this should be possible with the SDK that is specifically for working with these types of files.

You might take a look at ClosedXML which exists because the OpenXML APIs are not the nicest things to work with. There are implemented protection APIs so you should be able to see what someone else does.

@Murph Ack, I had meant to thank you for this suggestion! I ended up going with ClosedXML and, well, rewriting the useful parts of module I had already written on top of OpenXML with this.

@d2718 - not a problem, I'm pleased you've been able to solve your problems (or at least to move forward!)
